# Why is my npm dockerfile looping?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I'm containerizing a nodejs app. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:4-onbuild

ADD ./ /egp

RUN cd /egp \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y r-base python-dev python-matplotlib python-pil python-pip \
    && ./init.R \
    && pip install wordcloud \
    && echo "ABOUT TO do NPM" \
    && npm install -g bower gulp \
    && echo "JUST FINISHED ALL INSTALLATION"

EXPOSE 5000
# CMD npm start > app.log
CMD ["npm", "start", ">", "app.log"]
```

When I DON'T use the Dockerfile, and instead run

```
docker run -it -p 5000:5000 -v $(pwd):/egp node:4-onbuild /bin/bash
```

I can then paste the value of the RUN command and it all works perfectly, and then execute the `npm start` command and I'm good to go. However, upon attempting instead `docker build .` it seems to run in to an endless loop attempting to install npm stuff (and never displaying my echo commands), until it crashes with an out-of-memory error. Where have I gone wrong?

**EDIT**

Here is a minimal version of the EGP folder that exhibits the same container: logging in and pasting the whole "RUN" command works, but docker build does not.It is a .tar.gz file (though the name might download without one of the .)

http://orys.us/egpbroken

Comment: Do you have a minimal version of the egp folder that can be used to recreate your issue?

Comment: Added a minimal version of the context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node:4-onbuild image contains the [following Dockerfile](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/bf93fccf8e127824cd2478f491502c7d3ad0e1aa/4.4/onbuild/Dockerfile)

```
FROM node:4.4.7

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ONBUILD COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
ONBUILD RUN npm install
ONBUILD COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

The three `ONBUILD` commands run before your ADD or RUN command are kicked off, and the endless loop appears to come from the `npm install` command that's running. When you launch the container directly, the `ONBUILD` commands are skipped since you didn't build a child-image.  Change your `FROM` line to:

```
FROM node:4
```

and you should have your expected results.